# External ID not found in the system: portal.portal_projects

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to start the Odoo server on pycharm, when i debug it then it gives an errormessage. Can someone help me solve this error?

**error**

```
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: portal.portal_projects" while parsing /vagrant/odoo-server/addons/portal_project/portal_project_view.xml:22, near
**menuitem name="Projects" id="portal_services_projects" parent="portal.portal_projects" action="open_view_project" sequence="10"/>**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <record id="open_view_project" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Projects</field>
            <field name="res_model">project.project</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="domain">[]</field>
            <field name="view_mode">kanban,gantt</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="project.view_project_kanban"/>
            <field name="search_view_id" ref="project.view_project_project_filter"/>
            <field name="context">{}</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                  Click to start a new project.
                </p>
            </field>
        </record>

        <menuitem name="Projects" id="portal_services_projects" parent="portal.portal_projects"
            action="open_view_project" sequence="10"/>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: with this code I can't tell you where is error, and also if you are not using domain and context don't leave it empty just delete it.
odoo is telling you what is the error: id not found, that means that you specify id in wrong way, so you must fix it. error is not in action so line where you must fix is menuitem line.
I hope i helped you a little bit, with this code I cant tell you more

Comment: The  id of parent  "portal.portal_projects" not found, for resolve this problem, you must define the parent menuitem before menuitem name="Projects", in your xml, or in __openerp__.py file reorder the xml files

Comment: i resolved the problem, changed the module status from updating to installed in pgadmin db table, and refresh all the db then debug pycharm again, its working now.